# Escaping given list of characters in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

Was hoping someone could help me out a one-liner in bash, using anything standard like sed, awk, etc. to take a string and insert a backslash before any characters that are matched to a given list of characters.

For example, the input string `abj:"si8'h4#` should become `abj\:\"si8\'h4\#` if the list of characters I want to escape is `"':#`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What would you want the output to be if your input was `a\'b`? Should that result in `a\\'b` (i.e. an apparently escaped backslash) or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton good point! i should have pointed out that \ would be another char to escape, but i was just asking in general also... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) version.

```
echo 'abj:"si8'\''h4#' | perl -pe 's/(["'\'':#])/\\\1/g'
abj\:\"si8\'h4\#
```

The problem is how you want to input the list of characters to escape. If you're inputting them yourself, this solution will work fine, though you have to be careful with escaping single quotes. If you want to avoid escaping issues, perhaps you'd want to read the list of characters to escape from a file?

Comment: this works great as it is a static list that of characters I want to input, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
echo 'abj:"si8'"'h4#" | sed 's/["\x27:#]/\\&/g'
abj\:\"si8\'h4\#
```

Comment: this works great too! i am marking other answer as accepted to share the rep wealth though :D

Answer (score 1):

The set of characters that you want to escape as a variable:

```
$ esc="\"':#"
```

The string that you want to escape:

```
$ str=abj:\"si8\'h4\#
```

Escaping with `sed`:

```
$ echo "$str" | sed 's/['"$esc"']/\\&/g'
```

Output:

```
abj\:\"si8\'h4\#        <--- Output
abj\:\"si8\'h4\#        <--- Correct string for comparison
```

Yup, that seems to do it.